# Bootstrap popover dont work on panel-primary

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap panels, one panel-primary and another panel-default.
When i make the popover on the panel-primary it shows an empty modal, but on panel default it shows the text correctly.
Anyone had this problem?

I made an plunker code to show the problem:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign "   popover-placement="left" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="DUMMY TEXT"   ></span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eqPCkS8qgo6JF0eSb3W8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the modal is not empty. The problem is that the text `color` property is white. Just change the text color by your css.

```
.popover-content {
   color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.panel-primary` adds a white font color to the text, which of course can't be seen on the white background of the popover.

Therefore add this to your CSS:

```
.panel-primary .popover {
   color: #000;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LWTJrgFTHVlVNkPnTdFe?p=preview)